# How to tell all the differences between 2 SharePoint lists?

Tags: 2007, list-definition

I have 2 SharePoint servers (2007) a staging and production server.  Both have the same list but now that the test server is undergoing a few changes, the fields are somewhat out of sync.  Is there an any easy way to tell the differences between the test list and the production list to better aid me in syncing these 2 lists up?  Thanks!

Should clarify, I need to sync list structure, not list data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export the ListSchema (which includes everything that belongs to the list) of the two lists to XML files and compare the two using tool like WinDiff. You can use the "SharePoint Manager" tool (http://spm.codeplex.com/) to browse to the list you want and access the list schema from side panel.

Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this:
http://splistsync.codeplex.com/
Hope that helps

Comment: Not quite, need list structure, not list data